# giving access of another user to current user

Tags: linux

Let's suppose I have a folder:

```
/home/admin/website.com/stats
```

The above folder chown is `admin:admin`. I have another folder in `/home/agent/google` with chown `agent:agent`. That stats folder having a script that reads the file from Google folder. So I want to allow that stats folder to access the Google folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: You do not need to be owner in order to access a folder. Using CHMOD you can change the permissions to include all local users.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, folders don't access other folders; other users do. You could add the user you want to give access to the same group, or change the folder's group one the user's a member of?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I get it:

When you launch the script from the stats folder, a process of this script is launched. This process in most cases has the user id and group id of the user who launched it (unless suid or sgid bits on the executable file are set, then it will have user id and/or group id of the script file user/group). You can type 'id' to see what user and group id you launch the script with.

It is the process that tries to access the file from /home/agent/google. 
to access the file in /home/agent/google, the process has to be able 
1) to 'execute' the directory, 
2) to read the particular file from this directory.

For the directory, assuming that the process runs with userId and groupId other than agent, you need a directory to be world readable and world-executable (if not, you can do  chmod +0005 /home/agent/google).

For the file, to be able to read it, you need to ensure one of the following:

1. userId(process) is 0 (root) (you can run your script as a superuser, but generally it's a bad practice)
2. userId(process)==ownerId(file) AND file has read permissions for the owner. 'chmod u+r file'
3. groupId(process)==groupID(file) AND file has read permissions for the group. (you can set it with 'chmod g+r file'
4. file has read permissions for the world. (you can set it with chmod o+r file)

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Depends, which User is accessing the files. Folder will not read the files from another folder, User will do.
Example - Either it might be **Apache** which will access your files if you are running the script from browser, or the **admin** itself.
For simplicity,you can just give the **read** permission to **others** on **Google** directory -

`chmod u+r /home/agent/google`

If the file in **Google** folder needs to be executed also, then -

`chmod u+rx /home/agent/google`

Accordingly change the permissions for your file also.